# Traveling to Malaysia, Thailand and Singapore on Canadian Passport without tourist visa

Tags: thailand, singapore, canadian-citizens, malaysia

I am going on an Asia Tour. I have a Canadian passport.

1. Do I need any visa for going there?
2. Do I need a return ticket as well to enter there? can I use a one way ticket to Malaysia and also buy a one way ticket to Singapore. Would this work?

Comment: for going to 'Asia'? There are a LOT of countries in Asia...which ones? For the ticket question, the general rule is one qustion per post, I'd split that off into a separate question.

Comment: (I know your title says Malaysia ,but it's the 'Asia tour' which makes me worry it's more than one country)

Comment: Like Malaysia, then Singapore and Thailand

Comment: The rules for each country are different. You'd be much better off splitting this into one per country, for the countries where we don't already have an answer (some we do!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Visa:** It depends on how long you are staying in each country in your case. On this website you can look if you need a visa or not: http://www.doyouneedvisa.com/

**About the return ticket:** If you have a flight ticket out of the country you'll be safe eventhough it's to another country where you came from. If you don't have booked the tickets yet when entering the country, I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need a confirmed departure from whichever country you will first enter, be it Thailand, Malaysia or Singapore.  All three countries allow visa free entry, but for a limited time period and if you can not show that you are leaving the country before that time expires, the airline flying you there may not let you board.

Please know that this "proof" is pretty much limited to a confirmed air travel booking. A bus ticket to the border will not suffice.  A train ticket across the border (Thailand-Malaysia) might work but not always.

Similar rules exists within SE Asia when going to your next country, though these tend to be not as heavily enforced, BUT still are on the books and you could be subjected to the text of the law.

Comment: For Singapore-Malaysia, a very cheap train ticket only as far as the border can be ok, see [this question on the topic](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/absolute-cheapest-transport-from-malaysia-to-singapore-with-e-ticket-that-can-be) for more details

Comment: +1 for the singa-malaysia link above. The rules are actually more relaxed. If you look confident enough and carry reasonable money or alternate money with you, saying that I'll take the "XYZ" train from "A" to "B" on "X date" would be enough.

Comment: I arrived in Singapore several times without an onward ticket, nobody ever ask for it, The last time was in November 2014. I also been to Thailand and Malaysia several times and never did anybody ask for onward tickets. Can you provide links for these rules?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - you have been lucky it would seem.  From Timatic (the database airlines use - http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/) for Canadian citizens visiting Malaysia - Warning: Nationals of Canada not holding a return/onward ticket could be requested to purchase one or refused entry .... for Singapore - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry .... for Thailand - Visitors who are visa exempt but do not hold return/onward tickets could be refused entry.  Bottom line airlines are supposed to assure that you have a departure booked.

Comment: And I have personally witnessed Immigration in Thailand at Suvarnabhumi Airport ask arriving passengers to show their outbound tickets.