# Is a flight from KL sufficient proof of onward travel from Singapore?

Tags: australian-citizens, proof-of-onward-travel

Flying from Bali Denpasar to Singapore in a few days.

We have nothing booked yet, but we're planning on taking a bus / train to Malacca and then on to KL, from where we fly to Phuket.

Should I try to book a bus ticket to Malacca or Jahor Baru ahead of time, or will a ticket KL to Phuket be sufficient proof that I intend to leave the country?

Travelling on Aussie passports if it makes any difference.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18615/fly-into-singapore-or-kuala-lumpur-on-one-way-ticket-to-begin-overlanding-trip

Answer (score 2):

I can't claim to speak for Singaporean immigration, but **yes**, I'm pretty sure that will be fine, assuming the flight departure is before your Singapore entry permit ends.  Malaysia (Johor Baru) is a short bus ride away and you can't even prebook tickets on most operators.